# Why doesn't wget -r get all FTP subdirectories?

Tags: wget, ftp

When I did the command :

```
 wget -r ftp://user:paswword@ftp.xxxx.ovh.net/
```

It's missing any sub-sub-directories. Does recursive FTP have a limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How many level deep are you getting?  If you need more than 5, you need to provide the `-l` option.

man wget

```
-r
--recursive
    Turn on recursive retrieving.    The default maximum depth is 5.

-l depth
--level=depth
    Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.
-m
--mirror 
Turn on options suitable for mirroring. 
This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, 
sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. 
It is currently equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.
```

Comment: What's happen if you don't know the depth level?

Comment: @dubis - just go for a ridiculously large number such as 999 or even 50000.  There may well be a limit, but it's probably quite deep.

Comment: Why I didn't think alone about :-) I tried `wget -m` it's worked very fine for me

Comment: @dubis you should reply your question, rather than comment or edit.

Comment: @Archemar I didn't understand what're you meaning the answer is "-m" option. Should I post that in my own new answer?

Comment: @dubis yes, if you solved it, you may answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

The -m option of wget is the unlimited recursion

```
-m
--mirror 
Turn on options suitable for mirroring. 
   This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, 
   sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. 
   It is currently equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.
```

Thanks for helping.